# Long Sanskrit string doesn't get hyphenated

Tags: hyphenation, polyglossia, indic

I am trying to get to work the hyphenation for transliterated sanskrit provided by polyglossia. One admittedly odd problem I encounter is that a string (four compound words actually, glued together by sandhi) spanning more than one line doesn't get hyphenated:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\setotherlanguage{english} 
\newfontfamily\englishfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}

asmadādiviśeṣaṇaśūnyasyārthasākṣātkāritvamātrasyaivendriyādhīnatvadarśanād anaikāntikatvam asambhavīti cet | yady evam arthasākṣātkāritvamātrasyendiryavadālokādhīnatvam upalabdham iti na santamase paśyeyur ulūkādayaḥ | atha vyabhicāradarśanād ālokasyāvyāpakatvam, vyabhicāraśaṅkayā tarhīndriyasyāpy avyāpakatvam | vyāptyā śaṅkā khaṇḍyata iti cet | śaṅkāsambhavād vyāptir evāsambhavinī yadi prathamata eva vyāptiḥ, vyabhicāro 'pi na dṛśyeta | 


\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Of course I could use discretionary hyphens here, but I would rather rely on latex (xelatex) taking care of the hyphenation. Why doesn't it work here?

Comment: xetex like classic tex does not hyphenate the first word of a paragraph, try \hpsace*{0pt}` at the start

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\hspace*{0pt}` at the very beginning of the paragraph, just before the word? Doesn't do it.

Comment: Yes I see same (even if I use `\hyphenation` on a copy of that string), not sure yet...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're being very unlucky: if I add `\tracingparagraphs=1` in the document, the log file shows the attempts made by XeTeX at line breaking; I also put `\hspace*{0pt}` at the start, so that hyphenating the first word will be possible.

```
@firstpass
@secondpass
[]| \EU1/TeXGyrePagella(0)/m/n/10 a-sma-dā-di-vi-śe-ṣa-ṇa-śū-nya-syā-rtha-sā-kṣ
ā-tkā-ri-tva-mā-tra-syai-ve-ndri-yā-dhīnatvadarśanād 
@ via @@0 b=* p=0 d=*
@@1: line 1.3 t=0 -> @@0
a-nai-kā-nti-ka-tvam a-sa-mbha-vīti cet | yady e-vam a-rtha-sā-kṣā-tkā-ri-tva-m
ā-tra-sye-ndi-
@\discretionary via @@1 b=16 p=50 d=3176
@@2: line 2.3- t=3176 -> @@1
rya-va-dā-lo-kā-dhī-na-tvam u-pa-la-bdham iti na sa-nta-mase pa-śye-yur u-lū-kā
-da-yaḥ | 
@ via @@2 b=3 p=0 d=169
@@3: line 3.2 t=3345 -> @@2
a-tha vya-bhi-cā-ra-da-rśa-nād ā-lo-ka-syā-vyā-pa-ka-tvam, vya-bhi-cā-ra-śa-ṅka
yā ta-rhī-ndri-
@\discretionary via @@3 b=13 p=50 d=3029
@@4: line 4.3- t=6374 -> @@3
ya-syāpy a-vyā-pa-ka-tvam | vyā-ptyā śa-ṅkā kha-ṇḍyata iti cet | śa-ṅkā-sa-mbha
-vād 
@ via @@4 b=3 p=0 d=169
@@5: line 5.2 t=6543 -> @@4
vyā-ptir e-vā-sa-mbha-vinī yadi pra-tha-mata eva vyā-ptiḥ, vya-bhi-cāro 'pi na 
dṛśyeta 
@ via @@5 b=1 p=0 d=121
@@6: line 6.2 t=6664 -> @@5
| 
@\par via @@6 b=0 p=-10000 d=*
@@7: line 7.2- t=6664 -> @@6
```

What can be seen is that no feasible hyphenation points are found in the final part of the long word

```
...-yā-dhīnatvadarśanād
```

and hyphenating after `yā` would give too short a line.

This has to do with the inability of (Xe)TeX to correctly hyphenate words longer than 63 characters, see part 42 “Hyphenation” in “TeX, the program” (`texdoc tex`, p. 344ff).

You have to add discretionaries, I'm afraid, or some `\penalty0 \hspace{0pt}` at appropriate points so automatic hyphenation would still be possible in the compound words.

For instance, inserting `\-` as shown below allows hyphenation, but the line is still overfull; hyphenating between `tva` and `da` would be no good either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}

asmadādiviśeṣaṇaśūnyasyārthasākṣātkāritvamātrasyaivendriyādhīnatvada\-rśanād
anaikāntikatvam asambhavīti cet | yady evam
arthasākṣātkāritvamātrasyendiryavadālokādhīnatvam upalabdham iti na santamase
paśyeyur ulūkādayaḥ | atha vyabhicāradarśanād ālokasyāvyāpakatvam,
vyabhicāraśaṅkayā tarhīndriyasyāpy avyāpakatvam | vyāptyā śaṅkā khaṇḍyata iti
cet | śaṅkāsambhavād vyāptir evāsambhavinī yadi prathamata eva vyāptiḥ,
vyabhicāro 'pi na dṛśyeta |

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How hard would it be to change the 63 characters to a higher number, or remove it alltogether? Searching for strings of more than 63 characters I get 1823 hits in the corpus of texts I'm working on...

Comment: @muk.li Unfortunately it is built in in XeTeX. You might ask on the XeTeX mailing list http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/xetex