# Getting rid of overfull line by reducing letter space

Tags: letterspacing

Related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294951/59023). I have an odd string which is longer than a line. Using only a discretionary I don't get a satisfactory result, as, if I get it right, LaTeX only uses word spacing to avoid over-/underfull hboxes, which is plainly not available in this line.

[image]

So I thought let me manually reduce the letter space here, by adding a new font, on whose LetterSpace value I experiment until it looks good:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\newfontfamily\shrink[LetterSpace=-0.5]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\begin{document}

\shrink{asmadādiviśeṣaṇaśūnyasyārthasākṣātkāritvamātrasyaivendriyādhīnatvada}\-rśanād
anaikāntikatvam asambhavīti cet | yady evam
arthasākṣātkāritvamātrasyendiryavadālokādhīnatvam upalabdham iti na santamase
paśyeyur ulūkādayaḥ | atha vyabhicāradarśanād ālokasyāvyāpakatvam,
vyabhicāraśaṅkayā tarhīndriyasyāpy avyāpakatvam | vyāptyā śaṅkā khaṇḍyata iti
cet | śaṅkāsambhavād vyāptir evāsambhavinī yadi prathamata eva vyāptiḥ,
vyabhicāro 'pi na dṛśyeta |

\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope though that there's a better (automatic) way of doing this, is there?